# progress bar: jump to a point

Tags: jquery, audio

I try to make a progress bar for audio as simple as possible. I was able to make a play and stop button and it works. I was able to make a progress graphic with a simple animate. (The song has 30 seconds and I animate the 30 milliseconds.) Now I am stuck with this problem:

How can I go anywhere in the song when I click in that part of the bar?

(I do not want any plugin. I try to do everything myself and understand each step)

Here is the code to play:
http://jsfiddle.net/396aP/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="play">Play</div>
<div id="stop">Stop</div>

<div id="progressbar">
    <div id="bar">
        <div id="indicator"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<audio id="audio" src="http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/075/Music/35/e5/c6/mzm.pffzpdco.aac.p.m4a">
</audio>
```

CSS:

```
#play {
    position:absolute;
    left:45px; top:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#stop {
    position:absolute;
    left:90px; top:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#progressbar{
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;

    height:4px;
    top:50px;
    left:45px;
}

#bar{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px; height:10px;
    background-color:#999;
}

#indicator{
    position:absolute;
    width:0px; height:10px;
    background-color:#333;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){       
    $("#play").click(function() {
      $("#audio").trigger('play');
      $("#indicator").animate({"width": "150px"}, 30000);
    });

    $("#stop").click(function() {
      $("#audio").trigger('pause');
      $("#indicator").stop();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is catching the position the mouse clicked try the following:

```
$("#progressbar").mouseup(function(e){
    var leftOffset = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var songPercents = leftOffset / $(this).width;
    var audio = $('audio');
    audio.currentPosition = songPercents * audio.duration;
});
```

I haven't tried it so I'm not sure it will work at the first try, but it should give you a start.

Comment: It does not work, but it gives me things to try. Thanks